# run Selenium in a Batch File

Tags: batch-file, selenium-rc

I want to create a batch file for running Selenium. I need it to run it in Jenkins, now you can ask why you will do it with a batch file? There is a plugin for it, so use that one. Now it is impossible to use that plugin because it is to complex what I want, so I need to do it with a batch file.

I'm using selenium-java-2.20.0 and Firefox.

Thanks already!

This is the code and the error that I get:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop>@echo off

C:\Users\User\Desktop>java -jar C:\Users\User\Downloads\selenium-java-2.20.0\selenium-2.20.0\selenium-java-2.20.0.jar -htmlSuite "iexploreproxy" "http://localhost" "C:\Users\User\Documents\Runner.html" "C:\Reports\Selenium\result.html"

Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from C:\Users\User\Downloads\selenium-java-2.20.0\selenium-2.20.0\selenium-java-2.20.0.jar
```

Comment: Maybe it's the space in 'C:\Users\User\Documents\ISAAC\Test Mogelijkheden\Selenium\Runner.html' between Test and Mogelijkheden

Comment: It's `@echo off` by the way, not `echo @off`.

Comment: @reos  I changed it to: C:\Users\User\Desktop>@echo off

C:\Users\User\Desktop>java -jar C:\Users\User\Downloads\selenium-java-2.20.0\selenium-2.20.0\selenium-java-2.20.0.jar -htmlSuite "iexploreproxy" "http://localhost" "C:\Users\User\Documents\Runner.html" "C:\Reports\Selenium\result.html"

Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from C:\Users\User\Downloads\selenium-java-2.20.0\selenium-2.20.0\selenium-java-2.20.0.jar 

And still getting the error..

Comment: That error means that the JAR file you're trying to run isn't an executable JAR file.

Comment: @adarshr But that is weird I think. That means that Selenium isn't runnable as server via Command Line. I went to seleniumhq.org/download/ and download there the 2.20.0 from Selenium Server (formerly the Selenium RC Server)

Comment: Not all Java applications are designed to be *runnable*. Some of them are just libraries which other runnable programs will utilize. Check if Selenium has a command line client for doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong JAR file.  You want [selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar&can=2&q=).

Comment: Fail! xD Oh my god.. Thanks mate!